# Trying to access static ConcurrentDictionary from another thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I get the folowing error:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
Additional information: Must create DependencySource on same Thread as the DependencyObject.

when i'm trying to access a static ConcurrentDictionary:

```
public static class Client
{
    public static ConcurrentDictionary<string, ImageBrush> ChannelMemberList { get; set; }
}
```

from the another thread like that:

```
this.ChannelMemberList = new Dictionary<string, ImageBrush>(Client.ChannelMemberList);
```

P.S. I try to copy this object. I think that happens because of referrence of the static object

Comment: Who knows what's going on in your program. The error message does not seem to be related to the given code, unless `this` would be a DependencyObject and `this.ChannelMemberList` would be a DependencyProperty or a property with a setter implementing some side-effect causing the problem down the line. Yeah, with the little information and little relevant code you offer in your question, all i can do is shrug my shoulders...

Comment: You are not allowed to access it from another thread and that is what the message is saying. You can only send a *message* to the thread who owns it and ask "pretty please can you do x for me". Search online please, there are plenty info about this.

Comment: Did you try to make client non-static? Just to understand if that's really the problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to wrap your assignment in a `Dispatcher`?

```
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(() => this.ChannelMemberList = new Dictionary<string, ImageBrush>(Client.ChannelMemberList););
```

Basically a `Dispatcher` is a "mediator" between your UI thread and your background thread, and with the call above you ask it to make the two threads communicate.

Comment: "_make the two threads communicate_" sounds a bit weird. The documentation for Dispatcher.Invoke is clearer: "_Executes the specified Action (delegate) synchronously on the thread the Dispatcher is associated with._"

Comment: The confusing fact is that Dispatcher doesn't work in this solution.